# How can i control loop alert pop-up by python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

when Some button click there's pop-up as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbI6w.png)
I want close pop-up and click that button until no pop-up appears.

driver = webdriver.Chrome
driver.get(URL)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/a').click()  << that button
da = Alert(driver)
da.accept()

How should I write the code?

I use while but it doesn't matter

pls help me for this question i join overstack flow.